# Thread.Sleep in Asp.net vNext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to make a call to a JSON api which only allows a limited number of requests per second to ensure no DDOS is happening from a specific IP.
It doesn't matter how long the requests take, as this will be done as an automated process overnight, however I need some way of pausing between each request to ensure my IP isn't temporarily blacklisted.

Now before I would of done Thread.Sleep(1000) to ensure only 1 request a second is sent, but in asp.net vNext Thread.Sleep doesn't work/exist so I cannot do this.

Is there an alternative or better way to handle what I need to do?
There is no bulk API so it has to be done 1 request at a time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you *certain* Thread.Sleep doesn't exist, rather than it just requiring a particular dependency? Btw, if you're writing async code, you should say so in the question as it significantly affects how you do this.

Comment: Well I added system.therading but the class Thread doesnt exist under it.
I.E. System.Threading.Thread does not exist in asp.net vnext, so unless it has been moved or I am missing a dependency, by default it is missing from the location I called it from previously.

Also this is not currently async.

Comment: You're missing a dependency - see my answer for details. In general, you shouldn't assume things are missing just because they're not present out of the box - there are *lots* of dependencies to use in DNX.

Comment: I didn't just assume it was missing, which is why i added doesn't work/does not exist as I wasn't sure and couldn't find any information about it online. Thankyou for pointing out however that I should be using thread.sleep if it is not async.

Never done async for stuff like this so that's the next step!

Thanks.

Comment: You *did* assume: you *stated* that "in asp.net vNext Thread.Sleep doesn't work/exist so I cannot do this" - and that's just not true. You made an *assumption* that it doesn't work or doesn't exist, rather than *asking* whether that was the case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000)
```

or

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000).Wait()
```

Also note that, *await Task.Delay* makes your executing thread reusable by other works, however Thread.Sleep blocks.

Comment: As noted in my answer, this isn't really appropriate IMO in non-async methods; it would be *at least* more idiomatic to use `Thread.Sleep` which definitely *does* exist in DNX.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a dependency. If your code is not async, you shouldn't use `Task.Delay`... you should use `Thread.Sleep()` or normal.

Just add the following dependency:

```
"System.Threading.Thread": "4.0.0-beta-23516"
```

Then you can use `Thread.Sleep` as normal.

Of course, if you *are* writing async code, then `await Task.Delay(...)` is appropriate - again, just like normal.